# How to navigate the file system in common lisp

Tags: shell, file-io, common-lisp, read-eval-print-loop

The more I write Common Lisp in a REPL (in Emacs/Slime), the more I'm annoyed about leaving the REPL to perform operations like making directories, listing files in directories, changing directories (although `,cd` is nice), etc.

So I was wondering if other Lispers used the REPL to perform the sort of file operations I'd normally use a shell for, and if so how they do it? The best I've managed starting to write a few wrappers around [uiop](https://github.com/fare/asdf/tree/master/uiop). Is there a better way?

Comment: Not enough to write an answer, but for daily file and directory usages, I simply leave it to Emacs, in particular `dired`. If am working from the REPL and needs to open a file knowing a CL pathname, I call [`ED`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_ed.htm) to open it inside Emacs (see also http://lispblog.xach.com/post/129215925278/my-new-favorite-slimesbclccl-trick).

Comment: Check out [CLASH - Common Lisp as SHell](https://clisp.sourceforge.io/clash.html).

Answer (score 4):

Not long time ago I had the same problem you have, so I made some research. Result:

**SHELISP: Unix shell commands from Common Lisp**:
http://dan.corlan.net/shelisp/

> Shelisp is a very short program that provides mechanisms for composing
>   and running Unix shell (particularly bash) commands and constructs
>   from Common Lisp.
>
> Essentially, it provides a '!' syntax that you can
>   use to run commands and a '[]' embedded mode where you can enter bash
>   scripts and obtain the standard output as a lisp string.
>
> Lisp expressions can be included in any command or script using a '?'
>   syntax. The new version also includes a 'sh' macro that allows to call
>   unix utilities directly with a syntax familiar to the lisp users.

I didn't use it yet, but I read manual and it looks interesting

Comment: FYI there is an updated fork on Github, renamed to Clesh: https://github.com/Neronus/clesh (Shelisp author knows about it).

Answer (score 4):

**The McCLIM Lisp Listener has some file/directory commands**

One unusual option is to use McCLIM. It's Lisp listener has a [bunch of commands](https://github.com/McCLIM/McCLIM/blob/master/Apps/Listener/dev-commands.lisp) and some of them are about files and directories. One can also add new commands.

Commands look not like Lisp calls, but they offer prompts, completion, help, dialogs, command listings, argument completion, etc. They are internally implemented by functions, but they work over typed objects with a lot meta information. Lisp objects (like pathnames) printed to the Listener are thus objects which the user interface recognizes as such.

Typical commands might be:

```
Show File /foo/bar.lisp
Show Directoy /foo/bar.lisp
Edit File /foo/bar.lisp
```

See the [McCLIM Lisp Listener](https://github.com/McCLIM/McCLIM/tree/master/Apps/Listener).

This comes from the Lisp Listener of the Symbolics Lisp Machine, which introduced the specific user interface and which had all kinds of fancy commands, not just file system commands. One could list a directory, and then the directory listing is a table of actual pathname objects - where one can invoke with the mouse a bunch of commands on displayed - depending on what it is: a host, a file, a directory, ... McCLIM allows similar things.

The main drawback of McCLIM is that the most used version of it is based on relatively raw X11. I would also expect it to be mostly used on Linux (or similar).

But on a Lisp Machine one usually had also a Filesystem browser - in addition to a Dired mode in Zmacs. The Filesystem browser was another application - with a really oldish user interface - which also had commands to deal with disks and similar.

Comment: This sounds ... amazing! I'm using a Mac day to day so this isn't an option for me, but the information about McCLIM, and the insight regarding how things were done on a Lisp Machine, are fantastic.